# Probability about winning prizes

Tags: probability

Chris plays in a game with $899$ other people, where there are $60$ TVs and $30$ stereos to win (equiprobability).  What is the probability that Chris wins exactly one stereo and one TV ?

We know he has $1/15$ to win a TV and $1/30$ to win a stereo but how can I find how he wins exactly one or both of them?

Comment: If I were giving out TVs and stereos as prizes, I might randomly rank the people, give a TV to each of the first 60, and a stereo to the next 30. Then the chance of winning both is zero, though the probability of winning each is respectively $1/15$ and $1/30$. But if someone can win multiple prizes, why not two TVs, or a TV and two stereos? Then the chance to win one TV is less than $1/15$. So I would read the original question more carefully and/or look at other problems by the same author for clues about how they meant this to be interpreted.

Answer (score 0):

Getting at least one TV is $\frac1{15}$, as you have stated.
 Now we must find the number of ways that the other TVs can be distributed amongst the other $899$ people, and divide it by the ways that the TVs can be distributed to everyone in the game.

Given that each TV can be given to any one of the $899$ people, we can multiply $899$ by itself over and over to get $899^{59}$ combinations to give $59$ TVs to the people in the game other than Chris.
 We use the same method to find that there are a grand total of $900^{59}$ combinations.

So the probability for Chris getting one TV is $$\frac{899^{59}}{900^{59}\cdot15}$$

Apply the same method to find that the probability for Chris getting one stereo is$$\frac{899^{29}}{900^{29}\cdot30}$$

EDIT: Multiply the $2$ fractions to find that getting both one TV and one stereo is $$\frac{899^{88}}{900^{88}\cdot450}$$

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I did this differently. The number of all possible outcomes is $$n={900\choose 60} \cdot {900\choose 30}$$ and the number of all good outcomes is $$m={899\choose 59} \cdot {899\choose 29}$$ So the result is $$ P = {m\over n} = {1\over 450}$$

**Can anyone confirm this?**

Comment: I think it depends on whether one person can win multiple prizes. It’s not quite clear in the Ops question

Comment: Suppose it can take at most one TV and at most one stereo @Xiaomi

Comment: I suppose not, given that OP said: “he wins exactly one”.

Comment: Who are you reffering to @Kyky He wins exactly one AND exactly second

Comment: It's possible, but I am just saying OP probably meant that.